# Cygwin Perl autodie 'not located'

Tags: cygwin, perl

I have Cygwin installed (with its native Perl support).  However, on running a make file supplied by a third-party, I get the following error:

Can't locate autodie.pm in @INC (you may need to install the autodie module)

What do I have to install in order to give Cygwin Perl support for the autodie mechanism ?  Is there a specific package that I need to add in Cygwin for this purpose ?

Comment: Hmm. It's part of perl-5.32.1-2, see  http://cygwin.net/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fperl%2Fperl-5.32.1-2&grep=autodie

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.  The solution is to install the Cygwin package listed below:

perl-Module-install